# Java code: add registry entry with cmd isnt working

Tags: java, windows, cmd, registry

Hello guys i want to add an autostart entry in windows registry with java:

```
String cmd[] = { "regex.exe add ","\"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\"", " /v ","\"Test\"", " /t ", "REG_SZ", " /d ", value };
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

sysout(value): `"javaw -jar C:\Users\name\eclipse-workspace\project\myjar.jar"`

sysout(cmd): `[regex.exe add , "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",  /v , "Test",  /t , REG_SZ,  /d , "javaw -jar C:\Users\name\eclipse-workspace\project\myjar.jar"]`

If i run my code i get some errors:

```
*Cannot run program "regex.exe add ": CreateProcess error=2, Cannot find your file
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
at Logger.log.main(log.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, 
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:483)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
... 4 more*
```

What did i wrong? I just want to add my jar into windows startup/autostart

Comment: I've had this problem before: It's not finding regex.exe. And the reason for that is the regex.exe is in windows32\system (or something like that) and you are running  a different directory. If you run cmd.exe first and execute regex.exe through that, it will have the PATH variable set up. But otherwise, you need to call regex.exe by full pathname

Comment: It still dont work:
I tried it like that:
-1 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /Marcel/user:Administrator cmd.exe "+ cmd);
-2 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + cmd)
Both times it works without an error but it doesnt add an registry entry .

With this i get the same error as first:
-String cmd[] = { "C:\\Windows\\System32\\reg.exe add ","\"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\"", " /v ","\"Test\"", " /t ", "REG_SZ", " /d ", value };

Comment: Sorry, I neglecte to say that once you have cmd running, you need to get the process OutputStream, add a PrintStream on the output stream, and use THAT to send in your regex instruction.

Comment: Can you show me the java code for this? Sorry i dont really understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Code example of my advice to start cmd.exe and use the OutputStream to send in the regex command:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /Marcel/user:Administrator cmd.exe");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(proc.getOutputStream());
String cmd = "regex.exe add " + " \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\","
+"  /v , \"Test\",  /t , REG_SZ,  /d , \"javaw -jar " + "C:\Users\name\eclipse-workspace\project\myjar.jar\" ";
ps.println(cmd);
//you should probably also listen for results of the above from the output and error streams
```

Comment: I get no error but its still not working. In windows console u have to type "reg add ..." instead of "regex.exe add" but if i try it in my program no key is created in the registry, even though it works if i do it per hand in windows console with the same command

Comment: @Marcel  There's probably an error either in the outputstream or the errorstream. You can/should attach a threaded DataFetcher (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) to both and print all messages out to the console.